# TableView Inside ScrollView IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, user-interface, uiscrollview

> I have a Tableview (Dynamic cell height) inside scrollview. The tableview's cells are dynamic as per the API data. I want to disable the scroll of tableview and make the scrollview longer as per the tableview height.

> Please suggest to me the best way to implement this UI.

> Here I have managed the scroll by the height of tableview ( fix height cell ) by the outlet of the tableview's height But I get stuck in dynamic cell height

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == classesTable {
            csHeightClassesTable.constant = 3 * 90
            return 3
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = classesTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LiveClassScheduleCell") as! LiveClassScheduleCell
        cell.setUp(isFromDoubt: true)
                
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 90
    }
```

[image: Here cell named Wednesday]

Comment: Did you tried to use section ? Seems appropriate in your case.

Comment: `UITableView` has all the scrolling functionality already... why are you trying to embed it in a scroll view?

Comment: I have some static content at the top and bottom of the TableView.

Comment: @KurbanAliMasu - that sounds like a table view header and footer.